# Dart, NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'options' when using CommandRunner

Tags: dart, command

Using the example here: http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/args/0.13.0/index.html

I'm trying to write a command line app, but I get `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'options'` when I try to use this example code. Why isn't `options` defined for the Command subclass instance? If I'm not supposed to use `options` then what am I supposed to use to access the options passed to this command?

Here's my code which also fails:

```dart
class ShuffleCommand extends Command {

  final name = "shuffle";
  final description = "Shuffle and choose cards from a deck";

  ShuffleCommand() {
    argParser
      ..addFlag('count', abbr: 'c', defaultsTo: "1")
      ..addOption('deck');
  }

  void run() {
    print(options);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the example should look like

```dart
import 'package:args/args.dart';
import 'package:args/command_runner.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  var parser = new ArgParser();

  var command = new ArgParser();
  parser.addCommand('shuffle', command);

  var runner = new CommandRunner('shuffle', '')
    ..addCommand(new ShuffleCommand())
    ..run(args);

}

class ShuffleCommand extends Command {

  final name = "shuffle";
  final description = "Shuffle and choose cards from a deck";

  ShuffleCommand() {
    argParser
      ..addFlag('count', abbr: 'c', defaultsTo: true)
      ..addOption('deck');
  }

  void run() {
    print(argParser.options);
  }
}
```

when you run it with `dart main.dart shuffle`, `run()` is executed and the options printed out.

Comment: This worked. Idk why it didn't occur to me that options was just a property of argParser.  I suppose keeping a dart implementation of python's `dir()` function would be handy.